# How to make facebook comment on website synchronize with facebook business page?

Tags: facebook-comments

I cannot get the comments from my facebook comments box (on website) to appear on my business facebook page

Comment box is up & working: http://bit.ly/GKGU78

If someone comments it does appear on the timeline of their Facebook page.

I have my own personal facebook page & I am the admin for a business page as well.

I need the comments from the website to appear on the business page but at the moment they only appear on my personal facebook page.

Can any wise soul advise on what changes I have to make to make this happen?